# Find the limit in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: limits, analysis

Let $x_1 = y_1 = 0$ and
$$
(x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) = \bigg(\bigg(1-\frac{2}{n}\bigg)x_n -\frac{y_n}{n} + \frac{4}{n}, \bigg(1-\frac{1}{n}\bigg)y_n - \frac{x_n}{n} + \frac{3}{n}\bigg).
$$
Find the $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n, y_n)$.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this problem. Expressions like
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = -3\frac{x_n}{n} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} \frac{x_k}{k} + \frac{H_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{3}{n},
$$
that can be derived from the definition of a sequence do not seem to be helpful. $H_n$ is $n$-th partial sum of Harmonic series.

Would be happy to see some suggestions.

Comment: Hi when you say that $x_0=y_0=0$ it means that is the limit of the sequences $x_n,y_n$?

Comment: Sorry, of course $x_1 = 0, y_1 = 0$. It has nothing to do with the limit

Comment: Well no problem, also the first notation was fine. The point is that we know where the sequence start but not yet where is going. I was just demanding a clarification in order to fully understand the question, let me think!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to prove that:
$$
\pmatrix{x_{n+1}-1 \\ y_{n+1}-2} = \pmatrix{x_{n}-1 \\ y_{n}-2} -\frac{1}{n}\cdot \pmatrix{2 & 1\\ 1&1}\cdot\pmatrix{x_{n}-1 \\ y_{n}-2} = \pmatrix{1-\frac{2}{n} & -\frac{1}{n}\\ -\frac{1}{n}&1-\frac{1}{n}}\cdot\pmatrix{x_{n}-1 \\ y_{n}-2}
$$

For the sake of simplicity, we denote
$$\pmatrix{z_{n}\\ t_{n}} :=\pmatrix{x_{n}-1 \\ y_{n}-2}$$
Then
$$
\pmatrix{z_{n+1} \\ t_{n+1}} = \underbrace{\pmatrix{1-\frac{2}{n} & -\frac{1}{n}\\ -\frac{1}{n}&1-\frac{1}{n}}}_{=:\mathbf{A}_n}\cdot\pmatrix{z_{n}\\ t_{n}} \tag{1}
$$

The matrix $\mathbf{A}_n\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is diagonalizable:
$\mathbf{A}_n = \mathbf{P}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{D}_n \cdot \mathbf{P}$ with
$$\mathbf{D}_n := \pmatrix{1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2n} & 0\\ 0&1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2n}}
\hspace{0.5cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.5cm}\mathbf{P} := \pmatrix{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} & 1\\ \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}&1}  \tag{2}$$
Interestingly, *the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ does not depend on $n$*.

We can then deduce the closed form expression for $z_n$ and $t_n$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$:

$$\begin{align}
\pmatrix{z_{n} \\ t_{n}} &= \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf{A}_i \right) \cdot \pmatrix{z_{0} \\ t_{0}} \\
&= \left(\prod_{i=1}^n  \mathbf{P}^{-1} \cdot \mathbf{D}_i \cdot \mathbf{P} \right) \cdot \pmatrix{z_{0} \\ t_{0}} \\
&= \mathbf{P}^{-1}\pmatrix{\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right) & 0\\ 0&\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)}\mathbf{P}\cdot\pmatrix{z_{0} \\ t_{0}}
\end{align}$$
And the closed form expression for $\pmatrix{x_n \\ y_n}$:

$$\color{red}{\pmatrix{x_{n} \\ y_{n}} = - \mathbf{P}^{-1}\pmatrix{\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right) & 0\\ 0&\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)}\mathbf{P}\cdot\pmatrix{1 \\ 2} + \pmatrix{1 \\ 2} }  $$

---

For the limit of $x_n$ and $y_n$, just notice that the terms $\left(1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)$ and $\left(1-\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)$ are in $(0,1)$ and decreasing for all $i \ge 2$.

By consequence, the two products $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2i}\right)$ are decreasing to $0$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$.

From that, we can conclude

$$\color{red}{\pmatrix{x_{n} \\ y_{n}} \xrightarrow{n \to +\infty }   \pmatrix{1 \\ 2} }  $$